# Flutter - In An Purchases - Not Found Products - Android - Google Play

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load my products from the Google Play store, but it's not working.

```
 @override
  Future<List<ProductDetails>> loadProductsStore() async {
    final isConnectedInStore = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();


    if (isConnectedInStore) {
      final response = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(ids);
      final products = response.productDetails;

      for (final element in response.notFoundIDs) {
        log('Purchase $element not found');
      }
      return products;
    }
    throw ErrorFirebase();
  }
```

Result Log:

[image]

I already made the configuration in the Google store but it does not bring

Answer (score 0):

I personally use revenueCat subscription service but one issue i encountered was that i forgot to make sure the simulator i was using allowed the use if the playstore. Not all simulators, commonly the newer models, have access to the playstore, once you set the device up sign in into a google account and that, if not done before, should allow you to see the subscriptions.

cheers